# one sided skew with css

Tags: css, skew

I want to create a one sided skew, but failed to do so. here is what I've tried so far:

```css
    .bg-style1 {
      background: #ccc;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    .bg-style1:after {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 30%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      background: #333333;
      -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
      -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
      transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    }
```

```html
<section class="page">
  <div class="bg-style1">
    .....content goes here
  </div>
</section>
```

but it is not working. look: [image]

what I want to accomplish:[image]

Comment: please post your HTML too

Comment: Your HTML code doesn't reflect what is in the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your `.bg-style1` rule and `transformX(-40%)` to the `transform:` in `.bg-style1:after`

```css
.bg-style1 {
  padding-top: ;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bg-style1:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #333333;
  -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="page">
  <div class="bg-style1">
    <h1>What is lorem ipsum</h1>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem because of parents background showing up at the left of skewed block. If yes then you should use `transform-origin: 0 0;`

```css
    .bg-style1 {
      background: #ccc;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    .bg-style1:after {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 30%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      background: #333333;
      -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
      -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
      transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<section class="page">
  <div class="bg-style1">
    .....content goes here
  </div>
</section>
```