# How do I apply the skewY() transform to only one side of a <div> element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div element to look like this: [image]

So how can I apply the skew transform property so that only one side(the bottom one here) gets tilted?

Comment: What do you need it for? Is it just the shape you need? If so you could use a border trick or clipping or 2 layered shapes or svg's or any of the other methods I just forgot. Otherwise it will get more complex (but it can be done).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279790/one-sided-skew-with-css

Comment: You can use [clip-path](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) to easily do a shape like you are looking for, but it doesn't have the best support yet. [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/gs84cdez/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
a {
  color: white;
}
.title {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 45px 20px 10px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;
    background: Grey;
}
.title:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 230%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: Grey;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transform: skew(0deg,-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can a triangle using the border trick on a `::before` pseudo element.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 30px;
}

div::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: -120px;
  right: 0;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 90px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
```